# Trying to simplify some Javascript with closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to simplify some JS code that uses closures but I am getting nowhere (probably because I'm not grokking closures)

I have some code that looks like this:

```
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var httpmethods = {    
        "GET": function() {
            alert('GET')
        },
        "PUT": function() {
            alert('PUT')
        }
    };
});
```

And I'm trying to simplify it in this way:

```
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var httpmethods = {    
        "GET": function() {
            alertGET()
        },
        "PUT": function() {
            alertPUT()
        }
    };
});

function alertGET() {
    alert('GET');
}

function alertPUT() {
    alert('PUT');
}
```

Unfortunately that doesnt seem to work...
Thus:
    - what am I doing wrong?
    - is it possible to do this?
    - how?

TIA

-- MV

Comment: `doesn't seem to work` is not a very precise problem description.

Comment: If you get a `alertGET is undefined` kind of error, you should try placing the function declarations before the `server` function. Other than that this seems perfectly legal.

Comment: What makes you feel it is simplifying things to move the anonymous functions outside?

Comment: Your code should work, you need to mention what is not working (what's the expected behavior) and what kind of error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Not setting up the object properly, you're putting the function names as strings inside the httpmethods object, instead of giving them names - try something like this:

```
var server = http.createServer( function (request, response) {});

var httpmethods = {
    get: function() { 
      alertGET()
    },
    put: function() {
      alertPUT()
    }
};

function alertGET() {
        alert('GET called');
}

function alertPUT() {
        alert('PUT called');
}

httpmethods.get()
httpmethods.put()
```

This is the way you define the methods inside the object, but not sure about the other stuff you have there (http.createServer()...?)

Comment: I've no idea what's inside the http.createServer() method.. without seeing the whole code, it's a little tricky, but the basic problem is the way you are defining the .get() and .put() functions on the httpmethods object. take the quotes off them, and it should be fine.

Comment: the quotes is of no issue - they are perfectly legal.

Comment: This example perfectly examplifies properties of object literals but does nothing to demonstrate closure.